# undo binding tab to auto-completion

Tags: python, readline

In python, tab auto-completion can be enabled for `raw_input` with `readline` module:

```
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

However, how can I revert the effect of the line above?

I have a program that needs tab to switch between auto-completion and `\t` for `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround:

```
readline.set_completer(lambda text, state: text + "\t" if state == 0 else None)
```

But still it would be better if `tab: complete` can be reverted